# Disable RAM memory caching for a particular program

Tags: ram, cache

I am running few benchmarks test using binaries made out of C. Is there anyway so I can ask kernel not to cache any part of these binary programs?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the kernel documentation on "drop_caches".

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt

Here's a small section:-

```
Writing to this will cause the kernel to drop clean caches, as well as
reclaimable slab objects like dentries and inodes.  Once dropped, their
memory becomes free.

To free pagecache:
    echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free reclaimable slab objects (includes dentries and inodes):
    echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free slab objects and pagecache:
    echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches

This is a non-destructive operation and will not free any dirty objects.
To increase the number of objects freed by this operation, the user may run
`sync' prior to writing to /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches.  This will minimize the
number of dirty objects on the system and create more candidates to be
dropped.
```

Comment: I tried this `free && sync && echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches && free` from a similar [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87909/52733), It didnt clear all cache but most of it